# Tkinter and openpyxl error no such file or directory ''

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, openpyxl

I have a program that uses tkinter and openpyxl to make an excel comparing program. Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl, csv
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

output = open('differences.csv', 'w', newline='')
output_writer = csv.writer(output)

wb1, wb2 = '', ''
sheet1, sheet2 = '', ''
column_1, column_2 = '', ''

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light green')
root.geometry("500x500")
root.wm_title("BananaCell")

e1 = Text(root, width=15, height=1)
e1.pack()
e1.place(x=70, y=150)

e2 = Text(root, width=15, height=1)
e2.pack()
e2.place(x=300, y=150)

column1_entry = Text(root, width=5, height=1)
column1_entry.pack()
column1_entry.place(x=135, y=250)

column2_entry = Text(root, width=5, height=1)
column2_entry.pack()
column2_entry.place(x=385, y=250)


def destroy():
    root.destroy()


def ask_for_filename_1():
    global wb1
    wb1 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    print(str(wb1))
    return wb1


def ask_for_filename_2():
    global wb2
    wb2 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    print(str(wb2))
    return wb2


def ask_for_sheet1():
    global sheet1
    sheet1 = e1.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(sheet1)
    return sheet1


def ask_for_sheet2():
    global sheet2
    sheet2 = e2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(sheet2)
    return sheet2


def get_col_1():
    global column_1
    c1 = column1_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(c1)


def get_col_2():
    global column_2
    c2 = column2_entry.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(c2)

filename_button1 = Button(root, text="Workbook 1", width=12, height=2, command=ask_for_filename_1)
filename_button1.pack()
filename_button1.place(x=100, y=100)

filename_button2 = Button(root, text="Workbook 2", width=12, height=2, 
 command=ask_for_filename_2)
filename_button2.pack()
filename_button2.place(x=300, y=100)

col_button1 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=5, height=1, command=get_col_1)
col_button1.pack()
col_button1.place(x=185, y=248)

col_button2 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=5, height=1, command=get_col_2)
col_button2.pack()
col_button2.place(x=435, y=248)

col1 = column_1
col2 = column_2

sheet_button1 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=6, height=0, 
command=ask_for_sheet1)
sheet_button1.pack()
sheet_button1.place(x=15, y=147)

sheet_button2 = Button(root, text="Enter", width=6, height=0, command=ask_for_sheet2)
sheet_button2.pack()
sheet_button2.place(x=430, y=147)

label1 = Label(root, text="Sheet 1 column letter: ", bg="light green")
label1.pack()
label1.place(x=10, y=250)

 label2 = Label(root, text="Sheet 2 column letter: ", bg = "light green")
label2.pack()
label2.place(x=260, y=250)


workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb1))
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb2))

worksheet1 = workbook1.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet1))
worksheet2 = workbook2.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet2))

col1 = column_1
col2 = column_2


def show():
    scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
    scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
    textbox = Text(root, wrap=WORD, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    textbox.pack()
    textbox.place(x=300, y=200)
    for (col, col_1) in zip(worksheet1.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col1), max_col=column_index_from_string(col1)), worksheet2.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col2), max_col=column_index_from_string(col2))):
        for (cell, cell_1) in zip(col, col_1):
           if cell.value != cell_1.value and cell.row == cell_1.row:
               textbox.insert(INSERT, 'Row ' + str(cell.row) + ' ' + 
str(cell.value) + ' is not equal to ' + str(cell_1.value) + ' ' + 'Row ' + str(cell_1.row) + '\n')


def write_csv():
    for (col, col_1) in zip(worksheet1.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col1), max_col=column_index_from_string(col1)), worksheet2.iter_cols(min_col = column_index_from_string(col2), max_col=column_index_from_string(col2))):
        for (cell, cell_1) in zip(col, col_1):
           if cell.value != cell_1.value and cell.row == cell_1.row:
               output_writer.writerow(['Sheet 1 value: ' + ' ' + str(cell.value) + '  ' + 'is not equal to ' + '  ' + 'Sheet 2 value:  ' + ' ' + str(cell_1.value) + ' ' + 'on row ' + ' ' + str(cell.row)])

show_button = Button(root, text="Show", width=8, height=1, command=show)
show_button.pack()
show_button.place(x=1, y=20)

button_export = Button(root, text="Export to CSV", width=10, height=1, command=write_csv)
button_export.pack()
button_export.place(x=450, y=60)

dButton = Button(root, text="Done", width=8, height=1, command=destroy)
dButton.pack()
dButton.place(x=100, y=60)

mainloop()
```

The program crashes and gives me the following error: `No such file or directory ''` and I am not sure it will fully run as planned. Can anyone rewrite my code to make it smoothly compile? Anything is great

Comment: Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Please create an [mcve]. You've posted a lot of code that doesn't appear to be part of the problem. Also, why are you calling `quit` and the later trying to create more widgets? It his highly unusual to have more GUI code after the call to `mainloop`.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have clarified my answer can anyone please help I have a deadline for the 15th of June please someone!!

Comment: Ask_filename some time throw error(cos using os model encoding). Creating a file for reopen use "sys.path.append(os.getcwd())". @BryanOakley is right need full traceback !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see of your code the problem is because you have not actually add the file names to the variables you are trying to use.

So when your program gets to the lines where `workbook1`, `workbook2`, `worksheet1`, and `worksheet2` are the program is trying to run the command `openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb1))` before the variables `wb1`, `wb2`, `wb1`, `sheet1`, and `sheet2` have been created. You need to have the functions that ask for the file name to assign to the variables to be called before you create the following:

```
workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb1))
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb2))

worksheet1 = workbook1.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet1))
worksheet2 = workbook2.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet2))
```

Here is an example of what you might want to do in order to accomplish this.

This is not the best way or even a good way but it will work for your needs in a hurry and give an example of what is needed for your workbooks and worksheets to be dealt with properly.

```
def ask_for_filename_1():
    global wb1
    wb1 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    print(str(wb1))
    return wb1

ask_for_filename_1() # add this line

def ask_for_filename_2():
    global wb2
    wb2 = askopenfilename(title="Select Workbook 1")
    print(str(wb2))
    return wb2

ask_for_filename_2() # add this line
```

you will need to do this for ever function that applies a file name to a variable before you work with said variables.

Keep in mind the example I gave is just to illustrate what needs to happen before you do anything with the variables `workbook1`, `workbook2`, `worksheet1`, and `worksheet2`. You may want to review and change your code so this is not a problem in the future.

Maybe add this section:

```
workbook1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb1))
workbook2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(str(wb2))

worksheet1 = workbook1.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet1))
worksheet2 = workbook2.get_sheet_by_name(str(sheet2))
```

to a function that is called after each `wb1`, `wb2`, `wb1`, `sheet1`, and `sheet2` have been created.

Comment: If this answer was helpful consider applying the bounty to this answer :D